# unicode Conversion String

Tags: apex, json

**JSON example:**

```
{"ResponseCode":"0","ResponseMessage":"&#x4F1A;&#x5458;&#x4FE1;&#x606F;&#x66F4;&#x65B0;&#x6210;&#x529F;&#x3002;","version":null}
```

**Problem:**

How to parse out the value of **ResponseMessage** in Apex?

I tried online parsing and it seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You deserialize the JSON as you normally would, using either a strongly-typed Apex class with `JSON.deserialize()` or the untyped `JSON.deserializeUntyped()`, and then access this parameter as a `String`. Once you've got that value, call the `unescapeHtml4()` method, which replaces these Unicode entities with their actual character equivalents.

All strings are stored in UTF-8, so representing Chinese characters on the platform is not a problem.

As an example, one could do this (a bit clumsily):

```
String jsonString = '{"ResponseCode":"0","ResponseMessage":"&#x4F1A;&#x5458;&#x4FE1;&#x606F;&#x66F4;&#x65B0;&#x6210;&#x529F;&#x3002;","version":null}';

System.debug(
    ((String)(((Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString))
             .get('ResponseMessage')))
    .unescapeHtml4()
);
```

This yields

> 21:36:59:010 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|会员信息更新成功。

which I cannot read, but which appears to match your expected text.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem.   : )

Comment: "Member information updated successfully", according to Google. 